Cut out walls and doors in Roomplan & SceneKit
I'm working on a SwiftUI project using SceneKit to visualize a 3D room. I'm trying to draw wall nodes with cutouts, similar to the default CaptureView. The left image shows my current result, and the right image shows what I'm aiming for.
Currently, my code looks like this:
func addSurfacesToScene(scene: SCNScene, surfaces: [CapturedRoom.Surface], surfaceType: SurfaceType) {
    for surface in surfaces {
        let node = createSurfaceNode(from: surface, type: surfaceType)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
    }
}

// Creates the surface node
geometry = SCNBox(width: CGFloat(surface.dimensions.x), height: CGFloat(surface.dimensions.y), length: CGFloat(surface.dimensions.z), chamferRadius: 0)
The addSurfacesToScene function adds surfaces to the scene, but currently, the SCNBox geometry creates solid walls without any cutouts.

How can I modify this code to create wall nodes with cutouts, such as windows or doors? Any suggestions or examples would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your assistance!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
